# How to select text in html inside div who have same class with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

im looking to get html of the text from this second div who have the same class(.hello) with cheerio:

```html
<div class="hello">blablabla</div>

<div class="hello"> 
<h2 id="coucou">Coucou</h2>
blablabla 2 html to <br> 
select this is the text I want<br>
blabla bla bla bal balbal blabla
</div>
```

The result I want :

```
blablabla 2 html to <br> 
select this is the text I want<br>
blabla bla bla bal balbal blabla
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
$('.hello + .hello').text()
```

In css, `+` means next sibling.

Comment: but sometimes , I have three class with same name, I have to get the text using the h2 id coucou

Comment: maybe `$('h2#coucou').parent()`